# Duplicates in Hibernate Query

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, jpa

I have a database that contains currently 2 different items but when i try to query the database the DAO returns a List of size 2 which is correct but each item in the list is the first item in the database instead of the two unique items . This has really puzzled me and I cant quite understand how or why it is doing this has anyone experienced this before?

```
    public List<Workout> getHistory(String username) {
    String sql = "from Workout w where w.username = '"+username+"'";
    return template.find(sql);

}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name="workout")
public class Workout {

    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Workout.class);    

    @Id
    @Column(name="username")
    private String username;

    @Column(name="added_date")
    private String added_date;

    @Lob
    @Column(name="workout")
    byte[] workout;

    public byte[] getWorkout() {
        return workout;
    }

    public void setWorkout(byte[] workout) {
        this.workout = workout;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getAdded_date() {
        return added_date;
    }

    public void setAdded_date(String added_date) {
        this.added_date = added_date;
    }

 }
```

Any help at all on this would be greatly appreciated.

Turns out there was no such problems with the unique ID, the problem was a serialization issue  caused by the set up of the default serialization of my workout class. Fixed now for the mean time thanks for your help!
Thanks in Advance
Chris

Comment: Show your `Workout` class and its mapping.

Comment: @axtavt should be up now , Thanks

Comment: Is there any eger fetched association?

Answer (score 1):

There might be a problem with unique key. 
Make sure your `@Id` fields represent the unique key.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have two Workouts in the db with the same username?

If so, then you shouldn't be using username as the id.

I don't know your domain. But at a guess I'd give each workout a unique id (probably a Long) and then username could be foreign key to a User object.

So you then should have something like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="workout")
public class Workout {

    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Workout.class);    

    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name="username")
    private String username;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you i wasnt aware the ID had to be unique without specifying it as unique

Comment: Sorry i tried creating an id on the table and i am still getting the same problem?

Comment: Have you updated your db appropriately after your schema change? I mean, can you enter 2 records with the same username? If not, then you should drop your PK constraint from your db table explicitly.

Comment: the db has now been changed so that there is a id PK and the query still returns the same results

Comment: Have you mapped the new id field in the workout object and annotated it with @id? Have you overidden the equals method? Maybe post an update/ask a new question.